# Ошибка в написании скрипта C# на нескольких одна и та же

Tags: c#

Вот эта ошибка:

> ```
> Error CS1617: Недопустимый параметр "4" для /langversion; ожидается ISO-1, ISO-2 или Default (CS1617) (Assembly-CSharp)
> ```

возникла в 2 скриптах. Пытался написать скрипт для управления персонажем в unity. Скрипты разные.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Charaktercontroller : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed =2f;
    float gravity = 20f;

    Vector3 direction;
    CharacterController controller;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            direction = new Vector3 (x, 0f, z);
            direction = Transform.TransformDirection (direction) * speed;
        }

        direction.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move (direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

ПОМОГИТЕ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380064/cs1617-invalid-option-6-for-langversion-must-be-iso-1-iso-2-3-4-5-or-de